# How to control delete functionality in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

**Question:**  Is it possible in CRM 2011 to control the delete functionality by using Plug-ins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is how do I keep users from deleting particular entities, remove their delete rights.

If the question is how to I not delete some of the time when a user attempts to delete a record based on some additional business rules, then yes, a custom Plugin is perfect.  Register it for the delete step in the pre-validation stage and fail the validation.

Here is a good getting started blog: http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2011/01/crm-2011-plugins-welcome-to.html

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestions-@Daryl. I will follow them.If possible,I would like to know,Is it possible to control the out-of-box delete functionality(stopping it from deleting) by using plug-in.(Exactly what i mean is for example, when we select a record and if we click on delete that record will be deleted,But I want that record to be not deleted even we click on delete button.Is it possible through plug-ins..?)

Comment: @Kittu I don't know how to explain it better than my answer already does.

Comment: @Kittu I agree with Daryl here. First you need to click your name at the top, enter your profile and make sure to accept the answers you've got (or explain what's missing). Secondly, to answer your question - yes, you can use a plugin to intercept the deletion but (1) you need to ask **that exact** question and (2) as Daryl points out, there might be better ways to deal with it. But the answer is yes, you can use a plugin to intercept the deletion process.

Comment: @Daryl,@Konrad Viltersten-Ok thanks for your suggestions,I am new to this community so I dint mark here after I will do.